# Create group using Office365 unified API returns 201 but doesn't work

Tags: api, office365, office365-apps

I am using  Office365 unified APIs preview to deal with Office 365 Groups, getting user groups endpoints works fine and returns user groups.

When I call create group endpoint, it retruns 201.created but the group doesn't exist in the office portal nor the get groups API call.

Here is the endpoint URL:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{MY_TENANT_NAME}/groups

Comment: It can take sometimes a few minutes for the group to propagate. Are you still not seeing it? Can you share the request payload you used, we will try and repro the issue.

Comment: thank you @RohitNagarmal-MSFT based on suggestion from office365 internal team, I had to add extra "unnecessary" directory permission... confirmed as office365 APIs bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally landed to a working solution.

if you are trying to create a group, you will need to also add another directory permission (unfortunately will need admin consent):

```
Read and write directory data
```

these are very weird behaviors from Office365 unified APIs, but we should excuse the APIs as you can see "beta" inside the endpoint URL.

Comment: This is correct for now.  However we hope to fix this shortly and I'll ping back on this thread when this is fixed.

Comment: Is this still the case?  I seem to be able to create Unified groups using the v1.0 Graph API (and fast too), but lots of subsequent API operations fail (eg calendar event setting) because they don't appear to have an SMTP mailboxes associated with them, despite having the _mailEnabled_ flag set to true.  Oddly accessing the group calendars from OWA does work!